# Getting real-time or delayed data of brokers into Flutter app

Tags: python, flutter, web-scraping

What is the best way to get current prices (bid/ask) of different trading instruments from different brokers into a Flutter app? I've been told that web scraping isn't that reliable, but some of the brokers just doesn't have proper Api endpoints.

Does anyone know any data aggregator that i can use?

Would appreciate if anyone can share their experiences.

Comment: need proper API .

Comment: Do you know any data aggregator for this?

Comment: I of no idea but you can check for Zerodha or any other reputed company's Developer page .